# Not sure how to properly do this

Tags: c#, .net-core

Ok, so working on a dotnet Core 2 console app that I'm designing to run either on Windows or *Nix.  Now the the part I'm trying to figure out is I want to only have one code base and let the code determine if it's running on Win then go one path, or if on *Nix go another path.

So what I'm thinking is create an Interface with the way I want the classes for the two paths to look as far as properties and methods, then create a Win and Nix class implementing the interface.

Seems straightforward, but what I am racking my brain on is how exactly do I create the object based on the OS?  I have wrapper code for "IsWindows" and "IsNix" that returns a boolean each, so my thought is to use a If statement to do this.  Not sure how to create a generic global variable, then instantiate it in the conditional statement.

Maybe I'm off my rocker and trying to do something odd here, if I am I'm not afraid to be told that.  My only other thought is to perform the work inside the conditional statement, but that really would negate my desire to create the object in the conditional based on the OS, then call the same code going forward, using the classes that implement the Interface to make the different code calls as appropriate.

Comment: What are you attempting that's OS specific?

Comment: Basically I am writing a bootstrapped for a third-party agent that is kinda flakey sometimes and is a little bit of a pain, so I need to have OS specific method for finding process status and such.

Comment: I downvoted due to the useless title, which makes this question more difficult for future readers to find.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Why not edit the post and add a more useful title?

Answer (score 0):

So I feel like a complete idiot with brain lock.  Simply creating an object of the type of the Interface is all I needed to do, then set it to an instance of the class in the conditional statement.  Easy peasy, not sure why I had a brain fart on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Having common interface and two classes implementing it for different OS'es is definitelly good approach. So let's assume you have

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class WinClass: IMyInterface
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Implementation of DoSomething for Windows
    }
}

public class NixClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Implementation of DoSomething for *nix
    }
}
```

Common way to instantiate different implementations of interface (or abstract class) based on certain conditions is using [Factory pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). This might look like this:

```
public static class MyInterfaceFactory
{
    public static IMyInterface CreateMyInterface()
    {
        if (IsWindows)
            return new WinClass();
        else if (IsNix)
            return new NixClass();
        else
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This is the only platform-dependent part of your code, rest of your code will use only `IMyInterface` and will be platform independent. You can either use this factory whenever you need to create new instance implementing `IMyInterface`, or you can use [Singleton pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) to ensure, that only one objects will be created for entire application:

```
public static class MyInterfaceSingleton
{
    static MyInterfaceSingleton()
    {
        Instance = MyInterfaceFactory.CreateMyInterface();
    }

    public static IMyInterface Instance { get; private set; }

    // In C# 7, you can use just this instead:
    // public static IMyInterface Instance { get; } = MyInterfaceFactory.CreateMyInterface();
}
```

Your application then simply call `MyInterfaceSingleton.Instance.DoSomething();` whenever needed, in a platform independent way.